# Your App build script points to an unknown file ./jni/Android.mk

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Obviously this question has been asked numerous times, however, I need to understand how the answer answers my question

the path of my jni is outside of my project, and linked to the project with a shortcut

I am working on windows, had this been on linux, there is a symbolic link, and this isnt a problem

the location of my `jni` is `PROJECT_LOC\..\Common\jni`

how do I write that in my `Android.mk` or `Application.mk` files ?

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts on Windows operate as Windows Explorer extension and are not handled by the filesystem. Therefore they don't work when they are used in paths (directly through the VFS), as opposed to using eg. Open File dialog which is actually a Windows Explorer window.

Windows support [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and [junction points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) (symlink to a directory). Use those.

Comment: isnt there just a variable i can use that just says "the Android.mk file is here" ?